# How to import Notepad++ style configuration into VSCode?

Tags: notepad++, xml, styles, visual-studio-code

I found the `stylers.model.xml` file in Notepad++, but unsure how to proceed from there. Dragging it into `AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extensions` inside a `theme-npp` folder seems to do nothing. Further, there are several styles in Notepad++ - only one  is of interest.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because [Notepad++](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HiSandy/npp-material-theme/master/Material%20Theme.xml) (example) and [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme) use very different formats for creating themes.

You will need to create your own VS Code theme based on whatever Notepad++ theme you like.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is using the NotepadPlusPlus Remixed Theme, available at the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sh4dow.theme-notepadplusplusremixed).